# Having trouble writing Regex Expression

Tags: python, regex

Trying to write the correct regex expression.

Example of rows I have

```
abc.org.bafdafwlbdfasfs  49392  in ns ns3.abc.org.
www.zyx.org.jkl;dfsfdsjkfw  49392  in ns ns3.abc.org.
aorg.org.fdfwada  49392  in ns ns3.abc.com.
etc, etc.
```

I want to only pull out THE FIRST domain name in each row.  I am not interested in the latter part of these strings.

```
abc.org
zyx.org
aorg.org
```

To summarize, I just want to pull the domain name itself.  The domain name could contain the characters "org" in it, so I want to search for ".org" and only pull characters directly in front of it along with .org.

Also, each line could contain two periods (example 2 above) where it reads [www.zyx.org.fdfswfj](http://www.zyx.org.fdfswfj)  It should only pull zyx.org.

Thank you!

Comment: Which programming language (if any) do you use?

Comment: Why 1rst line gives `abc.org` and 2nd `zyx.org` instead of `www.zyx`? What are the rules?

Comment: It looks like a question that can be answered, but tag your question with the language you are working in.

Comment: @Toto This is a long zone file.  It's just the way it is presented to me.  I didn't create the file.  Most are like xxx.org or xyx.org, but occassionally, they throw the www. in front.  The file is quite messy in general.

Comment: @Jan I am using Pyton

Comment: Are you saying that **all** TLDs are equal to `.org`? and you want to get the domain just before `.org`?

Comment: @Toto All TLDs are .org.  I want to get just the domain before .org AND ONLY for the first occurrence on each line.

Answer (score -1):

It is better and easier to use the available URL API object.
[More information here:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

Example:

```js
let url = new URL('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62919398/having-trouble-writing-regex-expression#62919398');
 alert(url.origin);
```

Comment: Many if not most of the lines actually contain more than one URL.  See my example.  I need to only return the first domain (if it exists) on each line and in the form XXX.org  Other data should be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

If all URLs end with "org" then here is a solution.

The array contains all the URLs as needed.

```js
function getFirstText(str) {
  return str.match(/(\w+.org)/gm);
}

urls = `abc.org.bafdafwlbdfasfs  49392  in ns ns3.abc.org.
        www.zyx.org.jkl;dfsfdsjkfw  49392  in ns ns3.abc.org.
        aorg.org.fdfwada  49392  in ns ns3.abc.com.
        etc, etc.`

myArrayofURLS = getFirstText(urls);

console.log(myArrayofURLS)
```

Comment: I worked around with this.  I am coding in python (novice), and modified it but couldn't get this to work.  Python answers are more helpful.